# Access Firefox/Chrome history

Tags: hard-drive, web-application

My old laptop crashed so I moved the hard drive on an identical laptop.

Identical laptop doesnt have Windows installed. So do I need to install Windows from scratch?

Also, once Windows is installed; can I access my old firefox and chrome web history?

Thanks bunch in advance!!

Comment: Yes, able to access old hard drive as an external drive from "another machine". But wasn't able to access old browser Chrome and Firefox history from old hard disk since the applications are resident and local to the "another machine"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know as long as the drive isn't encrypted, you should be able to right click on the top level folder (in this case you would want the user folder for the original user) and change to read and write so that you can access the files within. as far an I know the files you want are in "AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles" and "USERNAME/AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"

As for installing windows or not, if it is identical (down to the specs and model) you could try to boot from that drive using del or f2 to get to the bios and select that drive as the boot drive.

If the issue is that the drive doesn't boot properly, then yes you will have to install windows on the other drive (it sounds like you had 2 installed)

Comment: just copy the profiles over replacing the empty ones they make by default and try it